# It began with a Mourning Palace

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme

> Watch me in the deepest hole,
>   where you may find connection to my soul.
>   With an eye, I am a dagger.
>   You'll tell the children I do not matter.
>   I'll hide you when you need a hand,
>   be sure to seek permission to land.
>   Through time with Donnie you shall go,
>   revenge as Westlake you must sow.

What am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you

> the **dark**?

Watch me in the deepest hole

> Holes are typically **dark**, the deeper you go.

where you may find connection to my soul.

> Refers to the video game series, ***Dark*** Souls.

With an eye, I am a dagger

> Replacing the 'a' with an 'i' gives you **dirk**, a synonym for dagger.

You'll tell the children I do not matter

> Fear of the **dark** is common among children, and they are told it is nothing to worry about.

I'll hide you when you need a hand,

> It's easy to hide in the **dark**.

be sure to seek permission to land.

> *Permission to Land* is an album by *The **Dark**ness*.

Through time with Donnie you shall go,

> Refers to the movie *Donnie **Dark**o*, in which time reverses.

revenge as Westlake you must sow.

> Refers to Peyton Westlake, the identity of **Dark**man.

The title of the riddle refers to

> *Mourning Palace* from the album *Enthrone **Dark**ness Triumphant*

Comment: Yes! All correct well done :)